# Is there a way to filter incoming HTTP request by hostname?

Tags: web-services, callback, webhooks, whitelist, websecurity

We have developed a web application that integrates with a 3rd party service. One of the integration the 3rd party service would call our API server to update some status (something similar with payment gateway).

Initially the API on our server has no authentication, so we think we should have some checking in place to verify the callback is authentic.

The 3rd party service has already done with our project and refuse to modify code on their side, and their server has dynamic IP so we are unable to whitelist by IP. Their engineers suggested us to whitelist their hostname instead.

We have considered getting the source IP and reverse DNS. This approach only work in some cases, and would not work for example custom domain for a cloud VM. The resolved hostname would be the VM's hostname instead of the custom domain.

Their engineers sounded like this is a common practice and easy implementation, are we missing something? We have full control on firewall, DNS record and API code on our side.

Answer (score 0):

I think the common practice is to add mutual-authentication for your case. Your callback interface looks like an open api and you need to verify the callback parameters signature which encrypted by AES or RSA algorithm.
If 3rd party insist on not changing code, they could add a proxy server which has a fix IP.